# CSS items not being able to be moved to the left

Tags: css, html

When I try to move CSS elements to the right using `margin-right: 200px`, it doesn't move. However, `margin-left: 200px` does move. My CSS file is as shown:

```css
        .wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
      }
    
      
      .btc {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        padding: 0.75em 2em;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: 500px;
        color: #FFAA48;
        border: 2px solid #FFAA48;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 0.3em;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url(https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center left 11px;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
      }
      .btc:hover {
        background-color: #FFAA48;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #FFAA48;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a id='btc' class='btc' title='Bitcoin Current Price (USD)'>Loading...</a>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you have to add your html also

Comment: what is the expected result you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed body to relative and used right to fix it.

```css
body {
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:20%;
    right:0;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
  }


  .btc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.75em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 500px;
    color: #FFAA48;
    border: 2px solid #FFAA48;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 11px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
  }
  .btc:hover {
    background-color: #FFAA48;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFAA48;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <a id='btc' class='btc' title='Bitcoin Current Price (USD)'>Loading...</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With absolute `div`, you have to use `right` along with `margin-right`, or you could just use `right` instead of `margin-right`. In your case, I removed `margin-right` and removed `left` and used `right` only.

```css
.wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        right: 200px;
      }
    
      
      .btc {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        padding: 0.75em 2em;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: 500px;
        color: #FFAA48;
        border: 2px solid #FFAA48;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 0.3em;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url(https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center left 11px;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
      }
      .btc:hover {
        background-color: #FFAA48;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #FFAA48;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a id='btc' class='btc' title='Bitcoin Current Price (USD)'>Loading...</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0; /* left: 50% */
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```

You just have to change `left: 50%` to `right: 0`;